# FTP protocol in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

Is it possible to use the FTP protocol (with user and password) to download a very huge file (about 100GB) in a Codename One desktop app?

Is it possible to use the FTP protocol in all the Codename One supported platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing specific. It's possible the `URL` class will work but we can't guarantee it since its only been tested for http.

As long as you don't need SFTP, if I recall correctly the protocol is pretty simple. You can just open the connection using the TCP sockets cn1lib and just download through there. Alternatively a native interface is also a possibility.

Comment: Unfortunately the URL class is not usable, I just tried it: it seems that the implementation does not provide for the use of FTP. I'll take the other suggestions into account.